# Full screen gaming on 1 of dual monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

So I just got a dual screen set-up going and I have some problems with it.

When I try to put the game on full screen mode it will black out the other screen. Right now I have managed to get fix this by using a game in windowed mode and hiding my taskbar, but that is not really how I want it to work.

What I would like is to be able to get a full screen game on the one screen and something else open in the other screen. (how) is this possible?

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium, Nvidia Geforce GT630 2GB and the game tested in this case was Just Cause 2.

Comment: A lot of this depends on the OS, the application being run, and the video card being used.  If you can provide this information, better help can be given.

Comment: It's on there now.

Answer (score 0):

you can Press

<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

and select Computer only to disable dual-head prior gaming. 
Select Extend to enable.